# How to calculate "interference weight" between 20MHz, 40MHz and 11ac 80MHz APs?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11n, 802.11, 802.11g, 802.11ac

I want to know how to calculate the "interference weight" in the combination of APs running on different channel frequencies.

Lets say I have 10 APs in different operating modes, such as 11a, 11a/n and 11ac.

If an 11a AP is running a 20MHz channel say (36), and some 11a/n APs are running 40MHz channels (36 and 40), and some 11ac APs are running with 80MHz channels (36, 40, 44, 48).

Now how do these frequencies interfere with each other and how can I calculate the interference weight among these frequencies?

"Interference weight" means, like how much percentage that a channel is interfering with other channel. Like, AP1 and AP2 are running on channel say 48, we can say that they are highly interfering. And if they are running with little adjacent channels like (AP1 at 44 and AP2 at 48), there is partial interference, and if they are running in away channels there is no interference.

By this we can achieve a channel for an AP with less interference with reference to neighbors, we can select that channel as an automatic channel for that AP.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question properly is worthy of graduate-level academic research.

Optimizing automatic channel selection is a complex problem, and overlapping 20/40/80MHz channels is just one of many many factors. There are other, simpler factors that have an even bigger impact, including the signal strength of the interferers and how much airtime the traffic from those interferers is using.